# Testing chaincode Using dev mode network issue

Tags: testing, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am running “dev mode” by leveraging pre-generated orderer and channel artifacts for [a sample dev network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html)

here **cli** require image: hyperledger/fabric-tools by default it is trying to pull **latest** tag image and showing error[latest image](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-tools/tags/). and it throwing error 
`Error response from daemon: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest not found`

so I pull image **hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.0**, and rename it with hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest( not sure it is proper way or not ) by :

```
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.0
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.0 hyperledger/fabric-tools
```

My network is running successfully but unfortunately **cli container** is stopped running.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                            NAMES
d10d170cd2fa        hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.0     "/bin/bash -c ./sc..."   29 seconds ago      Exited (1) 27 seconds ago                                                    cli
163f494bb85f        hyperledger/fabric-ccenv                  "/bin/bash -c 'sle..."   59 minutes ago      Up About a minute                                                            chaincode
e96e86930d94        hyperledger/fabric-peer                   "peer node start -..."   59 minutes ago      Up About a minute           0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer
c568480e30d2        hyperledger/fabric-orderer                "orderer"                59 minutes ago      Up About a minute           0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp
```

Comment: How do you start up the network? What do you execute for it? Could you show more logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tools container as the cli container.

```
docker exec -it d10d170cd2fa /bin/bash
```

Comment: **docker exec** command executed only when the container's process is running.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post logs of cli container by issuing command `docker logs <containerId>`? cli container exit doesn't necessarily mean there's any error about the e2e test.

Answer (score 0):

If you started the services using docker-compose, you can run either of: `docker-compose restart -f docker-compose-simple.yaml cli` or `docker-compose up -f docker-compose-simple.yaml cli`.

However, if you started your network AFTER having tagged the fabric-tools image as above, you should examine the logs of your exited container with `docker logs cli`, to determine why it exited.

Answer (score -1):

It can be because of previously running docker containers. In my case  first time it worked correctly but it gave error in second time. Killing and removing created docker containers using 
`docker rm container_name`
and starting containers again, solved the problem.